# onclick of child element is causinf parent button to activate

Tags: javascript

I have 1 function that creates a new checkbox with a delete button to remove it. However when using onclick for the delete button, it causes the it to be deleted when the create checkbox is activated so that nothing is there in the first place.

```
<script>
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    var i = 0;

    function add_client(form) {

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id", "div"+i.toString())

        var check = document.createElement("input")
        check.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        check.setAttribute("id", "check"+i.toString());

        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.setAttribute("for", "check"+i.toString());
        label.setAttribute("id", "label")
        txtNode = document.createTextNode(form.value);
        label.appendChild(txtNode);

        var br = document.createElement("br");

        div.appendChild(check);
        div.appendChild(label);
        list.appendChild(div)
        i++;
        

        var del = document.createElement("input");
        del.setAttribute("type", "button");
        del.setAttribute("value", "Delete");
        del.setAttribute("id", "del")
        div.appendChild(del);
        del.onclick = del.remove();

        div.appendChild(br);

    }
</script>
```

i know this is a DOM issue but cannot get around it.... any ideas?

Comment: was using document.getelementbyid before but was causing errors due to it trying to remove before element was added to the document model

Comment: Not sure if that's the only problem but `onclick` expects to be assigned a function: `del.onclick = () => del.remove()`. You are currently calling `del.remove()` immediately (thus removing the element) and assign its return value (which is not a function) to `del.onclick`.

Comment: yep this was the problem, fixed the issue. thanks Felix.